# AndroVM-About WhatsApp settings and Background processes of the AndroVM

Tags: virtualbox, android

I'm using AndroVM on Virtual-box. And I have a question about WhatsApp and the emulator itself.

1. In windows I use BlueStacks and there inside WhatsApp I have settings icon to customize WhatsApp such as,

a. Changing whatsApp background(wallpaper).

b. Changing behavior or enter key.(come to next line or send the msg to receiver). etc

But in AndroVM I couldn't find any icon of settings inside WhatsApp.

2.In Bluestacks there was an icon like double rectangles one behind the other where I could see the recently opened apps which was running in background. And I could close them by swiping individual icons to right side.

But in AndroVM I can switch between opened apps using alt+tab key but I couldn't close them.
And I'm using Ubuntu.

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question because I couldn't find any AndroVM tag and suggest me the right place.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer accidentally by myself. The problem is with the resolution of the AndroVM.
By default the resolution was set to 1024x650. In this resolution we can't customize the WhatsApp settings or view recently opened apps. Go to Apps and select androvmConfiguration, then change the resolution to 1366x768. This will enable you to both customize the Whatsapp settings as well as background apps.

Comment: The image of both will be added once I get reputation constraint of this site fulfilled.